# como puedo obtener el valor de un select al editar un usuario en reactjs con Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap, react-bootstrap

al momento de editar un usuario, debo obtener el valor que este ha seleccionado previamente en un select y si este quiere modificarlo debe enviar el valor modificado,en este momento envio el valor modificado, pero no me trae el valor que el usuario ha seleccionado antes.

```
const [mUsrIdUpa, setUpa] = useState([]);
const [mUsrIdUpaSelect, setUpaSelect] = useState([]);
```

asi obtengo la persona:

```
const obtenerPersona = async (mUsrId) => {
  setShow(true);
  const idUsuario =mUsrId;
  const token = sessionStorage.getItem("Token");
  const Token = token.slice(1, -1);
  const respuesta = await Axios.post("/PostListarUsuariosId/",{idUsuario:idUsuario},{
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + Token,
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
  });
  console.log("la data que traigo es: "+JSON.stringify(respuesta.data));
  
  setUpa(respuesta.data.mUsrIdUpa);
}
```

la informacion que me arroja la consola es:

```
`{"mUsrId":"5090c5bc-cecc-4a8f-a542-5eeedbc46218",
"mUsrIdUpa":"Lestoma prueba"}`
```

el form lo tengo asi:

```
<Form.Group controlId="formUpa" className="col col-sm-6">
                  <Form.Label>Upa</Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control
                    as="select" 
                    onChange={(e) => setUpa(e.target.value)} value={mUsrIdUpa}
                  >
                   <option value="">Seleccionar...</option>
                    {mUsrIdUpaSelect.map((usrIdUpa) => (
                      <option key={usrIdUpa.mlUpsId}  value={usrIdUpa.mlUpsId}>
                        {usrIdUpa.mlUpsNombre}
                      </option>
                    ))}
                  </Form.Control>
                </Form.Group>
```

[al momento de editar usuario, asi es como lo muestra.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8z99w.png)

estuve investigando y lo que he intentado es  con el value en esta linea deberia traer el valor

```
<Form.Control
                    as="select" 
                    onChange={(e) => setUpa(e.target.value)} value={mUsrIdUpa}
                  >
```

pero no funciona.

soy nuevo en reactjs, alguien tiene una sabe como podria hacer?

Comment: No es clara la pregunta, según entiendo consultas un endpoint que te trae información de un usuario e intentas colocar el valor obtenido en un `<select></select>`

Comment: exactamente, eso es lo que estoy tratando de hacer

Comment: Pues solo te puedo comentar que lo he hecho usando un hook de react llamado useForm, es tan simple y sencillo como pasar cada input a tu hook y con la funcion reset poblas el formulario con la data traida del endpoint. podria dejarte un ejemplo como respuesta, si te interesa. y la [documentacion de use form aca](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/)

Comment: @David081, por favor podrias compartirme tu ejemplo, seria de gran ayuda. gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno primero que nada debemos tener en cuenta que los formularios nos permiten enviar informacion ingresada por el usuario, pero tambien en algunas ocasiones debemos cargarlo de información obtenida previamente (como es tu caso), o también resetear los valores .

como te comente mas arriba con `useForm` podemos realizar todas las acciones que mencione anteriormente y aca te mostraré como y te explicaré lo mejor posible.

Como puedes ver en el codigo, declaro el hook `useform` con 3 parametros: `register, reset, y handleSubmit`:

1. `register:` nos permite darle un "id" a cada input de nuestro formulario
2. `reset:` Este nos permite cargar la informacion obtenida a nuestro formulario
3. `handleSubmit:` Obtiene la informacion cuando se envia el formulario (submit)

En el siguiente fragmento de código tengo un formulario donde se ingresa el nombre y precio de un producto, una funcion para obtener la informacion del formulario, una función para cargar data en el formulario y una función para setear los valores del form en '', debo aclarar que esto sirve para cualquier elemento de un formulario (input, select, radio ,checkbox..etc)

```
import {useForm} from "react-hook-form"
export default function ListadoProductos(){ 
const {register, reset, handleSubmit } = useForm() 
const onSubmit = (data)=>{
   //Obtiene la informacion del formulario, useform lo hace todo
   //Y se basa en la declaracion de los inputs en el formulario con {...register('nombre del input')} 
   console.log(data) 
   // resultado esperado un objeto con la informacion del formulario
   //{id:'',nombre:"ejemplo", precio: 1500}
} 
const cargarform = ()=>{
   fetch("myendpoint", "GET").then(res=>{
      //rescato los valores devueltos por el endpoint en variables
      const { nombre, precio} = res.data;
      //Paso las variables al formulario  a traves de reset (funcion propia del hook)
      reset({ nombre, precio});
   })
}
const resetForm = ()=>{
   //Borra los valores ingresados anteriormente
   reset({ nombre :"", precio:""});
}
return( 
  <>
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
    <input type='hidden' {...register('id')} /> 
    <label>Nombre del producto</label>
    <input type='text' className='form-control' {...register('nombre')} placeholder='Ej:coca cola' required /> 
    <label>Precio </label>
    <input type='number' className='form-control' {...register('precio')} placeholder='1500' required /> 
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Enviar</button>)
  </form>
  </>
}
```

### Consideraciones

todo input debe ser declarado con `{...register('id')}`, de esto dependera que `useform` lo tome, y el id ingresado será la clave del objeto cuando rescate la información.

Para cargar la información obtenida del endpoint, si bien no es necesario, es una buena practica que las variables vayan con el mismo nombre que el id del input `{...register("nombre")}` = nombre

Esta es el [enlace](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/) donde saque toda la información te invito a probarlo